# NFSv4: machine gets unresponsive when share is accessed without ticket

Tags: redhat, nfs4, rhel8, rhel9

We are implementing NFSv4_kerberos for mounting of home directories on a RHEL 9 machine.
The think is that if a user has a cronjob that writes to the mounted homedir after the ticket expiration, the whole machine gets very unresponsive, to the point that I cannot even use the GUI.

Using `top`, I see this:

```
root      20   0  622392  74816  12876 R 100.0   0.9   1267:35 udisksd
1878994 ec-fran+  20   0  631432  41476   8300 R 100.0   0.5   2629:12 gsd-housekeepin
   2478 root      20   0  237100   2996   2688 S   0.3   0.0   1:33.41 GetMachineId.sh
   3467 root      20   0  531688  66192  11344 S   0.3   0.8  68:51.39 sssd_kcm
1878834 ec-fran+  20   0  598832  10692   8060 S   0.3   0.1  33:21.64 ibus-daemon
```

and sometimes this:

```
1878523 ec-fran+  20   0  121020  40352   8276 R  48.2   0.5 991:14.60 systemd
1879208 ec-fran+  20   0  722592  61232   8644 R  48.2   0.8 608:21.50 gvfsd-trash
3254251 root      20   0  124260  41240   8200 R  47.2   0.5   0:57.99 systemd
1878894 ec-fran+  20   0  731276  46704   9268 R  46.9   0.6   1572:14 gvfs-udisks2-vo
      1 root      20   0  276064  40796   9012 R  45.9   0.5   1030:26 systemd
   1601 gdm       20   0  123492  39796   8024 R  45.9   0.5 993:01.11 systemd
1878994 ec-fran+  20   0  631432  41476   8300 R  42.3   0.5   2629:58 gsd-housekeepin
   1936 gdm       20   0 4570320 259660 113184 R  42.0   3.3 663:24.11 gnome-shell
    837 root      20   0  622392  74816  12876 R  14.8   0.9   1268:09 udisksd
```

Is there a way to minimize this problem? We don't know ahead for how long a user will be idle, so as of now it would be too risky to use NFSv4 as all it takes is one idle user to make the whole VM unresponsive.

I see the the script I wrote to write something simple every hour to my home dir fails, but why the whole thing would make the machine unresponsive?

Here are the `journalctl -f` logs:

```
Apr 18 14:12:02 myhost.com systemd[1]: Started Session 31637 of user ec-fran.
Apr 18 14:12:08 myhost.com crond[3254526]: (mount.c:68): Messages from underlying mount program:
Apr 18 14:12:08 myhost.com crond[3254526]: (mount.c:72): mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting mystorage.com:/fp/homes01/u01/ec-fran
Apr 18 14:12:08 myhost.com crond[1314]: (mount.c:68): Messages from underlying mount program:
Apr 18 14:12:08 myhost.com crond[1314]: (mount.c:72): mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting mystorage.com:/fp/homes01/u01/ec-fran
Apr 18 14:12:08 myhost.com crond[1314]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of /fp/homes01/u01/ec-fran failed
Apr 18 14:12:08 myhost.com crond[3254526]: (pam_mount.c:522): mount of /fp/homes01/u01/ec-fran failed
Apr 18 14:12:08 myhost.com CROND[3254539]: (ec-fran) CMD (echo "meagain\n" >> ~ec-fran/test.txt)
Apr 18 14:12:08 myhost.com CROND[3254539]: (CRON) ERROR chdir failed (/fp/homes01/u01/ec-fran): Permission denied
Apr 18 14:12:08 myhost.com systemd[1]: session-31637.scope: Succeeded.
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [INFO][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] proton:1105 - Disconnected, already closed
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 - Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 40, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     return fn(*args, **keywords)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 611, in get
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     return self._impl.get(timeout)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/reliability.py", line 44, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     repair()
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/consumer.py", line 81, in repair
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     self.connection.open()
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/connect.py", line 29, in inner
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     impl = fn(connection)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/connection.py", line 91, in open
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     ssl_domain=domain)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/proton/_utils.py", line 395, in __init__
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     msg="Opening connection")
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/proton/_utils.py", line 529, in wait
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     raise Timeout(txt)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 - proton._exceptions.Timeout: Connection amqps://rhsat-prod01.uio.no:5647 timed out: Opening connection
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 - Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/consumer.py", line 98, in read
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     message, document = reader.next(wait)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 40, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     return fn(*args, **keywords)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 645, in next
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     message = self.get(timeout)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 45, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     raise ModelError(*e.args)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 - gofer.messaging.model.ModelError: Connection amqps://rhsat-prod01.uio.no:5647 timed out: Opening connection
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 - Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 40, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     return fn(*args, **keywords)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 584, in open
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     self._impl.open()
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/reliability.py", line 45, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     return fn(messenger, *args, **kwargs)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/consumer.py", line 72, in open
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     self.connection.open()
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/connect.py", line 29, in inner
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     impl = fn(connection)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/connection.py", line 91, in open
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     ssl_domain=domain)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/proton/_utils.py", line 395, in __init__
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     msg="Opening connection")
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/proton/_utils.py", line 529, in wait
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 -     raise Timeout(txt)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.adapter.model:44 - proton._exceptions.Timeout: Connection amqps://rhsat-prod01.uio.no:5647 timed out: Opening connection
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 40, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     return fn(*args, **keywords)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 611, in get
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     return self._impl.get(timeout)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/reliability.py", line 44, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     repair()
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/consumer.py", line 81, in repair
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     self.connection.open()
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/connect.py", line 29, in inner
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     impl = fn(connection)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/connection.py", line 91, in open
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     ssl_domain=domain)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/proton/_utils.py", line 395, in __init__
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     msg="Opening connection")
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/proton/_utils.py", line 529, in wait
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     raise Timeout(txt)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - proton._exceptions.Timeout: Connection amqps://rhsat-prod01.uio.no:5647 timed out: Opening connection
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/consumer.py", line 98, in read
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     message, document = reader.next(wait)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 40, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     return fn(*args, **keywords)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 645, in next
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     message = self.get(timeout)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 45, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     raise ModelError(*e.args)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - gofer.messaging.model.ModelError: Connection amqps://rhsat-prod01.uio.no:5647 timed out: Opening connection
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 40, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     return fn(*args, **keywords)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 584, in open
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     self._impl.open()
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/reliability.py", line 45, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     return fn(messenger, *args, **kwargs)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/consumer.py", line 72, in open
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     self.connection.open()
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/connect.py", line 29, in inner
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     impl = fn(connection)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/proton/connection.py", line 91, in open
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     ssl_domain=domain)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/proton/_utils.py", line 395, in __init__
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     msg="Opening connection")
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/proton/_utils.py", line 529, in wait
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     raise Timeout(txt)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - proton._exceptions.Timeout: Connection amqps://rhsat-prod01.uio.no:5647 timed out: Opening connection
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - Traceback (most recent call last):
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/consumer.py", line 72, in open
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     self.reader.open()
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gofer/messaging/adapter/model.py", line 45, in _fn
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 -     raise ModelError(*e.args)
Apr 18 14:12:55 myhost.com goferd[1055]: [ERROR][pulp.agent.1bd4c9ff-d49f-40f9-a651-91971b29919f] gofer.messaging.consumer:79 - gofer.messaging.model.ModelError: Connection amqps://rhsat-prod01.uio.no:5647 timed out: Opening connection
```

Any tips on how to minimize this problem?